# I want to create an extensible app via plugins with C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, plugins, extensibility

I want to create an app that will be extensible via plugins.

I know that I have 2 options.

1. I can create my own interpreted language and app with a built-in interpreter for this language.
2. I can use one of the existing languages such as Python, Lua or another scripting language.

I want to use option 2. And I know that I must create a layer for external language to enable communication between this language and my app. But I don't know how to do it. Maybe I must use interprocess communication or something like that.

Let's assume that I have an application written in C++. In the beginning, it may be even a simple console app that displays a few options. And I want to write a plugin in Python like this:

```
option = "additional option"
myApp.addOption(option)
```

And then:

1. I launch my app
2. My app loads the plugin
3. I see my app with this additional option displayed

I want to do this simple thing to understand how it works and then I will be able to do something more complicated.

Comment: On which [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)? That matters a lot!

Comment: I use the Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: Please accept my deepest condolences for that fact. In my biased opinion, Linux is much more developer friendly than Windows 10 is

Comment: I have Virtual Box and Linux Machine installed on it. But I can't get used to it. I know that GUI is not the most important think on Linux. The most important thing is the power of the console, safety, and a few other things. But I think that Linux is firstly for administrators and secondly for developers. I am not an administrator, I am a developer and just user. So I want to have both a reliable, safe, developer-friendly environment and intuitive, comfortable interface. I think MacOS have both. But I am just a poor student and I have not money for apple xD

Comment: My opinion is that Linux is or was for developers. The first users of Linux (in the previous century) have been developers. I used GNU/Linux in 1993 and at that time could not have been able to use it without developer skills. At that time, you had to recompile the [kernel](http://kernel.org/) for your graphics card. Read about [unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) and about [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)

Comment: In learned Unix in 1987 by reading [`man` pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) (for SunOS3.2) on paper from section 1 to section 9. Today you can read it on the web: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/ but at that time the [World Wide Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web) was in it early infancy. I basically used (professionally) the Internet in France before the Web even existed. [Sun 3/160](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-3) workstation.

Comment: Today, you have good documentation for Linux on the web: http://www.tldp.org/ and https://www.gnu.org/software/ and Google will find you a lot of Linux related tutorials

Comment: Both [Debian](http://debian.org/) and [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) are newbie friendly [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)s that runs on most PC hardware. You just need to download one of them and install. You'll find tutorials explaining how to do that and help from https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ but backup important data before installing (the disk could be formatted and/or repartitionned during installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that, with care, a C++ library can be called from a C program, mostly by appropriately using `extern "C"` to disable [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). On Linux, read also the [C++ dlopen mini Howto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/).

Then you need to read the chapter [*Extending and embedding the Python interpreter*](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html)

At last, Python is open source, so please study its [source code](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/).

> I can use one of the existing languages such as Python, Lua or another scripting language.

I strongly recommend considering using [GNU Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or extending [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/).

And both [TensorFlow](https://tensorflow.org/) or [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) could inspire you, since they are open source libraries (coded in C and/or C++) usable from Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by looking at the languages' documentation(if you're new):

Python -->https://docs.python.org/3/
Lua --> https://www.lua.org/docs.html

C++ libraries can also be called in C(If you're careful enough),you could look at this too
https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/